# Wrong number of arguments for DoCmd.OpenReport in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, compilation, adp

Sorry if this is a noob question, but I have been given the dubious honour of supporting an ancient legacy Access 2000 .adp application, written badly by someone years ago who is no longer around, when i have little experience with Access or VB myself :)

I have set up a WinXP dev machine with Access 2000 (it's an Access 2000 project) to do some support work. There is a pre-existing line of code which is supposed to print a report, which calls DoCmd.OpenReport with 6 arguments:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName, acViewPreview, , "orderId = 1234", , Printtype
```

When I run it I get a compile error: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

So I used 'intellisense' on DoCmd.OpenReport, and my access VB code editor tells me it is expecting only 4 arguments, not 6: ReportName, acViewNormal, FilterName and WhereCondition. When I go to the object browser for the command, the definition is:

Sub OpenReport(ReportName, [View As AcView = acViewNormal], [FilterName], [WhereCondition])
    Member of Access.DoCmd (i.e. 4 args)

Looking on various posts on the web, some people seem to be passing 4 args, some 6. What gives? I'm guessing there are different versions of Access code libraries, and I have the wrong one. But I have no idea where to start resolving this. Anyone know Access and can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access 2000, the [OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa203712(office.10).aspx) method accepted 4 parameters:

> **DoCmd.OpenReport** reportname[, view][, filtername][, wherecondition]

where [, *parameter*] are optional.

In Access XP, [OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141526(office.10).aspx) gained 2 more parameters to give:

> **DoCmd.OpenReport** reportname[, view][, filtername][, wherecondition][, windowmode][, openargs]

*Printtype* is being used as an argument to the report and will need to be passed in using another method, e.g. read from the form field or public property.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer, thank you! Installing Access XP instead of Access 2000 solved the problem. It's odd, it says in various window title bars that the project is Access 2000 format (thats why I isntalled Access 2000), yet the code is clearly targeted at Access XP.

Comment: The file format has more of a bearing on the limits of the jet database (table & record size) and the form and report properties (nested levels). So you can use a Access 2000 file format in Access XP but you now using VB6 (Visual Basic for Applications), as seen in the Tools > References dialog of the Code window.

Comment: @Ajw   Actually the file format which makes a difference as to the size of the MDB file is Access 97 and older which were only 1 Gb.   Access 2000 and hewer/Jet 4.0 support a 2 Gb file size.

Comment: @James   You can work with A2000 and A2002/A2003 format MDBs in Access 2003.   However to make an MDE from an A2000 MDB you must be in A2000 or convert the MDB format to A2002/A2003.

Comment: @Tony I used http://www.databasedev.co.uk/access_specifications.html to remind myself of the differences between 2000 and XP.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything after the WhereCondition argument. The additional arguments are for later version of Access (they are for WindowMode and OpenArgs)

Comment: doesn't that suggest that perhaps the poster hasn't applied the latest service pascks for Access 2000 and the Jet engine?

Comment: I installed all the latest service packs, this didnt resolve the issue. The problem was I needed Access XP (see accepted answer)

Comment: Access XP or later, you mean.